# Use the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem to prove that $S_4= \langle(1,2), (1,2,3,4) \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Using the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem or otherwise, prove that $S_4= \langle(1,2), (1,2,3,4) \rangle$? I am having a little bit of difficulty with this question, because I am not sure what it is asking. Should I consider working out the order of the stabiliser and orbits explicitly? Kindest regards.

Comment: Your group (allegedly it's $S_4$, but your job is to verify this) acts on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ in the way you'd expect, so it's a subgroup of $S_4$. If you can find something with an orbit of size $4$ and stabilizer subgroup of order $6$, then since $S_4$ has a unique subgroup of order $24$...

Comment: @pjs36 isn't it the case that the stabiliser of G is simply the identity therefore orbit must have a size 24?

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale Orbits are subsets of $X$, the set of elements we are permuting. Here $X = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$, hence $|X| = 4$ and the largest possible length of an orbit must then be $4$, not $24$.